# Check if a web page has change which requires login / cookie

Tags: python, cookies, authentication, mechanize, urllib

I'm using this code that I found online to check a webpage to see if it has been modified since the last time it was checked.  However I now have a need for it to work behind a site that require authentication that is done via another webpage, not the target.

Typically how I would handle this in a non-python way is export the cookie and pass the cookie to what program would be accessing it, say with wget.

I think I need to use mechanize however I'm having a hard time finding out how to import or set the one cookie I need.  Hopefully someone can point out what seems to be evading me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys, urllib
savepath = '/home/.checkurls/'

errormsg = '%s: %s: No such file or directory'
urlspath = savepath + 'urls.txt'
for path in savepath, urlspath:
        if not os.path.exists(path):
                print errormsg % (__file__, path)
                sys.exit(0)
urlfile = open(urlspath, 'r').readlines(); urlstring = ''
for url in urlfile:
        if not 'http://' in url:
                url = 'http://' + url
        url = url.replace('\n', '')
        filename = url.replace('/', '%2f')
        if '-v' in sys.argv:
                print '%s: %s ...' % (__file__, url)
        if not os.path.isfile(savepath + filename):
                urllib.urlretrieve(url, savepath + filename)
        filelines = open(savepath + filename, 'r').readlines()
        urllines = urllib.urlopen(url).readlines()
        if not filelines == urllines:
                open(savepath + filename, 'w').writelines(urllines)
                urlstring += '"' + url + '" '

if urlstring:
        os.popen("echo 'Page changed!' | mailx -s \"Update:\" $user")
else:
        if '-v' in sys.argv:
                print '%s: nothing for today' % __file__
```

I was hoping to just set the cookie or import it, however doesn't seem like any of my attempts are in the correct format and then just continue to use mechanize.urlopen and mechanize.urlretrieve.

The cookie data is here:

```
my.college.edu        FALSE   /       FALSE   0       SUMO_REGISTRATION_AuthCo
okie    57DCC7BFF9A58C9D0
```

Comment: The formatting gets really awkward around `if urlstring:` is that a mistake of transcribing it to SO or is that a mistake in the program?

Comment: Another question here has some sample code with cookies and `urllib`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886573/cookies-with-urllib

Comment: Nope, copy and paste.  The above program works just fine.  However I now have a cookie that I want to add to the request.